# How query works with missing Group by values

Tags: sql, oracle

I am tryng to write a query to pull the total discount as well as revenue of my customer's orders by day. Note that for each ship_id there will be several items so I want to have the sum clauses as below and in the end, I have that group by and I want to group them by ship_id (this is unique for each order).

I got a result of 2M rows (this could be correct because we are a big) but I am not sure if my group by is correct. What if I only put ship_id there? How my query understands it?

```
            d.ship_id 
            ,to_char(d.order_datetime,'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss') as datetime_order
            ,to_char(d.order_datetime, 'D') as day_order
            ,to_char(d.order_datetime, 'MM') as month_order
            ,sum(di.discount) as discount 
            ,sum(di.price * di.units) AS price 

        FROM 
            table1 d 
            JOIN 
            table2 di
            ON 
                d.ship_id = di.ship_id
       GROUP BY
            d.ship_id
            ,to_char(d.order_datetime,'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss') 
            ,to_char(d.order_datetime, 'D') 
            ,to_char(d.order_datetime, 'MM')
```

Comment: Try it, you'll get a syntax error.  mySQL has group by extensions which allow you to omit non-aggregated fields in the select from the group by.  Oracle does not.

Comment: You'll get a syntax error from what you have shown; you can't have `as day_order` in the group-by clause. Presumably that's an error creating the question though as you imply this works. I'm a little confused by what you want though - you said you wanted to query by day, and later by ship_id; but you're actually getting and grouping by the exact time of the order. Are you trying to get two levels of grouping at once, perhaps - total by day, and total by day/ship_id?

Comment: Please disregard the as... , I forgot to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

**In this query you grouping result by**

- ship_id (order)
- d.order_datetime  yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss (i think this is wrong if you need group only by day) this group is grouping by day,month,year,hour,minute and seconds
- d.order_datetime 'D' (grouping by day correct)
- d.order_datetime 'mm' (grouping by month correct, doesn't change results of grouping by day)

P.S.: I dont see grouping by costumer in anywhere.

Comment: Grouping just by D and MM would be a problem if you had data that spanned more than a year. Using `trunc(order_datetime, 'MM')` instead of `to_char()` might make more sense. But just `trunc(order_datetime)` would group by day - still not sure what the OP really wants *8-)

Comment: group by YYYY/MM/DD then

Answer (score 0):

Your query will sumarize all values groupped by itens on group by:

If you put, something like:

```
Select ship_id, ,sum(di.discount) as discount 
        ,sum(di.price * di.units) AS price from table1 group by ship_id
```

The query will return Price and discount groupped by ship_id, when you make a group by you must put all non-*aggregate fields on group by.

*Aggregate funtions (Sum,AVG,count...)

Try explain better your problem to make me understand your situation(problem).